# What is the magic ball of every day?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*Part of the [everyday object series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22everyday+object+series%22+is%3Aquestion)*

> Look at this magic ball of every day!
>   Knock it too hard and it runs away.
>   Heat it up to stop its run in its track,
>   But once it turned firm there's no going back.
>   It might become a new life, or nourish one old.
>   Beneath its plate of armor lies a heart of gold.

What is it?

Comment: Not to be picky, but do you mean "its" instead of "it's"?

Comment: @Brandon_J I changed the spelling, hope it's correct now.

Comment: Looks great now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is:

> An egg

*Knock it too hard and it runs away.*

> If you break an egg the contents will run out of the shell.

*Heat it up to stop it's run in it's track,*

> When an egg is cooked its inner becomes solid and won't run anymore.

*But once it turned firm there's no going back.*

> The inside of an egg normally

*It might become a new life, or nourish one old.*

> When an egg hatches a new creature comes out. If it hasn't been eaten beforehand.

*Beneath it's plate of armor lies a heart of gold.*

> Underneath the shell an egg contains a yoke.

Comment: lol 13 second difference between our answers.

Comment: Damn that was quick! Congratulations.

Comment: Uh thanks, but to be fair, I believe @Brandon_J answered a few seconds before me.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> An egg.

Look at this magic ball of every day!

> Eggs are everyday objects.

Knock it too hard and it runs away.

> The egg breaks when hit and the contents "run" out.

Heat it up to stop its run in its track,

> Cooking(heating) the egg solidifies the contents of the egg and makes it less runny.

But once it turned firm there's no going back.

> You cannot uncook an egg.

It might become a new life, or nourish one old.

> If the egg is fertilized, it becomes a chick, which is a new life. If not, it will be cooked to nourish a human that can eat solid foods.

Beneath its plate of armor lies a heart of gold.

> The golden-colored yolk lies under the hard shell of the egg.

Comment: [Actually you can](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/unboiled-egg-untangles-a-knotty-protein-problem/).

Comment: Darn science. But for the average citizen, ya know, it's impossible. @noedne

Comment: @Elmy I think I was in first, but barely